# outsized vs. outsize

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Like many, I have often come across phrases such as "outsized influence" or "outsized contribution". However, once when trying to apply this myself, it was suggested (I think it was by a grammar checker) that that correct way to say this was actually "outsize influence" etc.

Checking the dictionary, this appears to be correct – though using "outsized" in this context is probably [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=outsize%2Coutsized&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coutsize%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutsized%3B%2Cc0), including in literature.

Which is correct? Are both correct?

Comment: The phrase occurs both ways, because attributive _outsize_ and _outsized_ both are correct. This happens frequently to adjectives formed originally from participles -- the suffix is no longer useful because it's no longer a verb (if it ever was -- there is no verb _outsize_ with the correct meaning), and it gets dropped in conversation. /d/ is not an easy thing to say before many consonants. Before a vowel like _influence_, you can occasionally hear the /d/; but in _outsized beaver dam_, for instance, the /d/ disappears. Similar with _soft-shell(ed) crabs_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I often see this with "teenage" / "teenaged". "Outsize", "soft-shell", and "teenage" have never been English verbs (as far as I'm aware), so I wonder whether the "-d"/"-ed" endings are actually participial suffixes or something else. (We have "-en" for "golden", "wooden", etc., but AFAIK there is no general "-d"/"-ed" suffix for non-verbs.)

Comment: I think it's mimicry of the -ED/-EN past participle ending, as participles become more adjectival in use.

Comment: There are lots of words/word elements with -ed like -legged, -eyed, -eared, -nosed, which don't mirror verbs, although others like -coated, -backed, -topped, -sized, -painted, etc, might be connected with verbs even if they're similar in meaning.

Comment: @StuartF I wasn't tagged, so I didn't notice JL's or your remark until just now. Yes, -ed is definitely an adjective-forming suffix (I've actually written about it on another question, I think using the example "brown-eyed girl"); I think I was just having a brain-fart that day. In any case, it might be somehow related to the past participle ending, as JL suggests, but is certainly used for non-verbal adjectives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a term that has—according to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003)—been around since 1845 as a noun and since 1880 as an adjective, *outsize/outsized* didn't make much of a dent in Ngram frequency graphs until around 1920. Over the past century, however, the trajectories of *outsize* (blue line) and *outsized* (red line) have been quite interesting:

[image]

After holding a substantial edge in frequency of appearance in print from 1920 to about 1980, *outsize* saw it frequency plummet in the early 1980s, only to stabilize gradually after 1990 and increase modestly in the early 2000s. Meanwhile, *outsized* rose steadily until 1980, then endured a slight drop in frequency for a couple of years before recovering and rising faster that ever starting in about 1990. It passed *outsize* in frequency in 1994 and as of 2019 seems to be a bit more than twice as common as *outsize* in recent Google Books database publications.

According to the *Eleventh Collegiate*, *outsize* may function as either a noun or an adjective, whereas *outsized* functions only as an adjective. It seems reasonable to doubt that noun use of *outsize* has been very significant over the past sixty years, given the vanishingly small frequency of occurrence of *outsizes* since about 1960 in the following Ngram chart for *outsize* (blue line) versus *outsized* (red line) versus *outsizes* (green line) for the period 1900–2019:

[image]

But even if we suppose that all instances of *outsize* in print involve use of the word as an adjective, *outsize* as an adjective is now considerably less common in print than *outsized* as an adjective.

Even in 2003, Merriam-Webster listed *outsize* in the preferred position of first spelling in its entry for the adjective:

> **outsize** *also* **outsized** *adj* (1880) **1 :** unusually large or heavy **2 :** exaggerated or extravagant in size or degree

MW has followed that preference since introducing *an entry for *outsize/outsized* as an adjective in the Seventh* Collegiate (1963). Real-world usage, however, may be ignoring the prescribed preference in the *Eleventh Collegiate* and in other dictionaries, such as the *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010).

Only one usage commentator I consulted took up the question of *outsize* versus *outsized*—and his treatment is brief to the point of being peremptory.  From Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, third edition (2009):

> **outsize,** adj.; **outsized.** The first is standard. The second is a NEEDLESS VARIANT [defined elsewhere as "two or more forms of the same word without nuance or differentiation—and seemingly without even hope for either"].

When a variant form becomes twice as frequent in print as the standard form, it may be appropriate to revisit the question of which form is standard and which is a needless variant—or whether the concept of a "needless variant" is useful in appraising the situation.

An argument in support of a form on the basis of historical precedence may exert some emotional pull, but it can't stand up to popular usage in the long term. Thus, for example, a search for *hath* at Early English Books Online (which covers books published in English no later than the seventeenth century) yields 2,604,169 matches in 47,027 records, whereas a search for *has* yields 423,473 matches in 18,375 records. So you might have argued in 1700 that *hath* was standard and *has* was a needless variant, even though [momentum was already on the side of *has* by 1700](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hath%2C+has&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). At some point, however, the argument that *hath* is standard because of its older claim to being standard fails against the overwhelming fact that *has* eventually became much more popular.

Today, *outsize* still has a substantial number of adherents (I'm one of them). But on the evidence of the Ngram plots, I am not inclined to agree with Bryan Garner that *outsize* is standard and *outsized* is a needless variant.